# Splash Screen Android XML

Tags: android, xml, viewmodel, splash-screen

I'm trying implement splash screen using *Splash Screen Api* for android app with navigation component. I've faced with problem when i need to keep splash for some state from fragment viewmodel and in the same time app crashes if i call *installSplashScreen* not in *MainActivity*. I don't know how resolve this, seems i need add custom fragment splash without api. Any ideas?

```
installSplashScreen().apply {
     setKeepOnScreenCondition {
         homeViewModel.homeCollectionState.value !is HomeCollectionState.Loading &&
            homeViewModel.homeCollectionState.value !is HomeCollectionState.Idle
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach the ViewModel to the activity and the fragment.

You need to scope it to the activity to make sure you get the same instance.

In your activity:

```kotlin
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

In your fragment:

```kotlin
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```